# Sql Server Case Statement gives me errors in user-defined function

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I want to use a case statement in my user-defined functions because I need to match on a number of terms. I could use a table for the matches but then I wouldn't be able to put it inside the Computed Column definition.

This works with IF statements:

```
CREATE FUNCTION MaraSizeNumber
(
    @ms varchar
)
RETURNS varchar
AS
BEGIN
    IF ms = '16-18' RETURN '1'
    ELSE IF ms = '18-20' RETURN '2'
    ELSE IF ms = '20-22' RETURN '3'
    ELSE IF ms = '22+' RETURN '4'
    ELSE IF ms = '24+' RETURN '5'
    ELSE IF ms = '14-16' RETURN '7'
    ELSE RETURN 'BAD'
END
```

But with the original style using a CASE...WHEN THEN BLOCK I get an error message.

```
CREATE FUNCTION MaraSizeCaseExample
(
    @ms varchar
)
RETURNS varchar
AS
BEGIN
    CASE ms
        WHEN '16-18' THEN RETURN '1'
        WHEN '18-20' THEN RETURN '2'
        WHEN '20-22' THEN RETURN '3'
        WHEN '22+' THEN RETURN '4'
        WHEN '24+' THEN RETURN '5'
        WHEN '14-16' THEN RETURN '7'
        ELSE RETURN 'BAD'
    END
END
```

I get an error of Incorrect Syntax near case and incorrect syntax near when for my when parts.

I have correctly batched everything up because my last CREATE FUNCTION block ends with the GO, and according to the documentation on CASE, I have the right syntax.

I have a larger scalar function I'm building that will use the other scalar functions to generate the production coding in our system corresponding to other parameters. It would be best to be able to use CASE because the production coding depends on the product and the customer.

I also get an extra error in the second example at my Create Function line that says, "Incorrect Syntax: 'Create Function' must be the only statement in the batch", but with everything else identical I don't get that error with the IFs.

What am I doing wrong, or are CASES only allowed in SQL queries rather than scalar functions? The error messages are coming from SQL Server Management Studio's squiggle error message system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The case statement should look like:

```
RETURN CASE @ms
       WHEN '16-18' THEN '1'
       WHEN '18-20' THEN '2'
       WHEN '20-22' THEN '3'
       WHEN '22+' THEN '4'
       WHEN '24+' THEN '5'
       WHEN '14-16' THEN '7'
       ELSE 'BAD'
  END
```

Comment: ms needs to be @ms and the code isn't going to work anyway, because all the varchar variables are defaulting to varchar(1)

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem is because you are not specifying the size on your varchar (which is defaulting to 1).  This is resulting in the input and the output being truncated to a single character.  (You were also missing an `@` on your variable inside the function.)

So `PRINT dbo.SizeExample('16-18')` will print `'B'` (which is not only truncated, it's also not the answer you probably want, which is `'1'`)

Try instead:

```
CREATE FUNCTION MaraSizeExample
(
    @ms varchar(5)
)
RETURNS varchar(3)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN CASE @ms
        WHEN '16-18' THEN '1'
        WHEN '18-20' THEN '2'
        WHEN '20-22' THEN '3'
        WHEN '22+' THEN '4'
        WHEN '24+' THEN '5'
        WHEN '14-16' THEN '7'
        ELSE 'BAD'
    END
END
```

1. `CASE` is just a searched (or lookup) expression - you cannot `RETURN` from inside it - it's kind of like like `IIF()` in VB or `IF()` in Excel.  The earlier answer basically explained that.
2. `VARCHAR` means `VARCHAR(1)`, so you would get truncation - i.e. you'd never see `'BAD'` coming out, only `'B'`.  I'm not sure why you don't get a truncation warning when it happens like you get on some `SQL` `INSERT`, but there you go.
3. `@ms` is your variable's name.  I'm not sure why ms would be accepted unless there was some other database object by that name (a table?) - and even then it wouldn't be.  All variables and parameters in `T-SQL` are prefixed with `@` like this.

Comment: So I can't reference my variable just by its name? I have to use @ms everywhere?

Comment: Tony, I think what he's trying to say is that without specifying the size of the VARCHAR it's returning, if you pass in an invalid input (which would result in the output being 'BAD'), you'd get back just 'B'. So you should set the length of the VARCHAR to whatever maximum size you'd expect.

Comment: I think I did three things wrong. I'm new to Stored Procs and Scalar Functions in SQL Server

1. Shouldn't have included the return in the then clause of the CASE.
2. Set the size of varchar
3. Refer to variables by @var?