# Case statement in SQL gives error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

What am i doing wrong here?

```
CASE WHEN @Activity = 'XXXX' THEN
     SET @AccrualBase = @PrevAccrualBase
     SET @AccrualDate = @PrevAccrualDate
     SET @All_In_Rate = @PrevAll_In_Rate
     SET @AmtOut = @PrevAmtOut
END
```

I tried enlcosing the 4 set statements in BEGIN END but no luck. Pls advise

Comment: You're not asking a proper question. That's what you're doing wrong.

Comment: `CASE` in T-SQL (if you're talking about SQL Server and T-SQL) can only **return an atomic value** - it is **NOT** a flow control statement and **cannot** return/execute code statements

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server CASE statement gives me errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302833/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Case is an inline sql statement, so a bit of a pain for what you're doing. Probably better just to use `IF`

```
IF @Activity = 'XXXX' 
BEGIN

     SET @AccrualBase = @PrevAccrualBase
     SET @AccrualDate = @PrevAccrualDate
     SET @All_In_Rate = @PrevAll_In_Rate
     SET @AmtOut = @PrevAmtOut

END
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for IF statement:

```
IF @Activity = 'XXXX'
BEGIN
     SET @AccrualBase = @PrevAccrualBase
     SET @AccrualDate = @PrevAccrualDate
     SET @All_In_Rate = @PrevAll_In_Rate
     SET @AmtOut = @PrevAmtOut
END
```

Comment: +! Much better solution